# navigating between 2 activities in which one of them is graphics heavy

Tags: android

I have this situation that I am not sure about the right design/way of doing things.

I have an activity where user would spend most of his time (Call it Activity A). Then the user can go to another activity where it is more graphics intensive (Call it activity B). Activity B would have around 40 Imageviews that have looping drawable animations. The user will be navigating back and fourth between those activities multiple times.

Is the expectation to create Activity B every time the user navigate to it and reinitalize the the 40 views based on the stored Data in my application class (it has coordinates and the type of view created)?

Or is there better way?

Thank you

Comment: can you try fragment for performance

Comment: I didn't hear of this before. Any explanation? and possible advs/disadv

Comment: learn about fragment [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Following flag with intent to resume same activity without recreating it:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Comment: Oh great Idea! So how do I do that? Like when I start activity B or when backbutton is hit to go to activity A

Comment: when you start Activity B. Like Intent bActivityIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class); bActivityIntent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(bActivityIntent);

Comment: But when I navigate back to Activity A, Activity B will be destroyed by then. Thats the problem

Comment: Use this code in ActivityB:--- public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    super.onBackPressed();
}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using activities, you can use fragmentA and fragmentB
When you switch between two fragments, data of them will not be lost.

Comment: Is Data shared between fragments as well? Or do I store the shared data on the Application class ( Thats what I am doing as it is complex form of data and I dont want to use intent to pass it around)

Comment: You should store fragments as varialbes in activity class, then you can make getter method for them. Whenever you want to pass value from a fragment to other, just call `getActivity().getFragmentA().yourmethod(value......)`

Answer (score 1):

learn about fragment [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

you can use fragments with in the single activity. fragments are easy to swicth between another fragment. so did not lose data of another fragment.

Comment: Is Data shared between fragments as well? Or do I store the shared data on the Application class ( Thats what I am doing as it is complex form of data and I dont want to use intent to pass it around)